# как рассчитать устройство?

Tags: maple

Как определить усилие, развиваемое одноштоковым гидроцилиндром, с площадью штока 10 мм и площадью поршня 20 мм, при монометрическом давлении 20 атмосфер.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что оффтопик